# Get time difference in query

Tags: mysql

I have this query, and i need to find the difference between two time format.
So i need to add a clause, which would be:

```
WHERE end-date - start-date should be between 01:00:00 and 05:00:00
```

Could you help me with turning it to a mysql statement?
Thanks

```
 $data = mysql_query( "select r.`time`, r.`epos_id`,r.`basket_value`, r.`date`,re.`location`,i.`user_id`,i.`mobile_number`,
       i.`time`, i.`rbpos_id`, i.`date`
from retailer r
join rbpos_epos re on r.epos_id = re.epos_id
join imovo i on i.rbpos_id = re.rbpos_id
             WHERE  TIMEDIFF(i.`time`, r.`time`)<'01:05:00'
             and r.`time` < i.`time`
             and r.`date` = i.`date`;
")
```

Comment: [MySQL Date and Time functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html) You can just subtract dates and times...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [TIMEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_timediff) mysql function

Comment: Yes but i need to estimate that the difference between this two fields should be between : 1-5 hours

Comment: Do you mean `TIMEDIFF(start_date,end_date)<04:00:00` ?

Comment: I think so. just this is the correct way: `TIMEDIFF(end_date,start_date)<'04:00:00' `

Comment: i get this error: Incorrect parameter count in the call to native function 'TIMEDIFF'

Comment: are you sure, you are passing it two values?

Comment: can you show the result of `SELECT start_date,end_date FROM your_table LIMIT 1`?

Comment: sure, i get something like this :
16:24:25   18:24:25

Comment: check this: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bb51/3   Maybe smth. wrong with the field types?

Comment: pLEASE SEE MY UPDATED ANSWER, I DON'T KNOW WHAT I'M DOING WRONG :(

Comment: Maybe because you are using field name 'time' and it is a stored word in mysql. try changing the field name

Comment: I think i got it :)
could you please help me how to add the condition: li

Comment: WHERE  TIMEDIFF(i.`time_i`, r.`time_r`)<'01:05:00' and > '01:00:00'

Comment: WHERE TIMEDIFF(i.time_i, r.time_r)<'01:05:00' and TIMEDIFF(i.time_i, r.time_r) > '01:00:00'

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
SELECT TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF('05:00:00', '01:00:00'))
```

Comment: thanks, but where do i put both fields here? end date, start date?

Comment: YES, I DO need the difference!

Comment: SELECT end-date, start-date, TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(end-date, start-date)) time_diff FROM table

Answer (score 0):

TRY THIS

```
  SELECT end-date , start-date FROM `table` 
    where
  end-date - start-date between '01:00:00' and '05:00:00'
```

Answer (score 0):

`TIMEDIFF()` returns `expr1 – expr2` expressed as a time value. expr1 and expr2 are time or date-and-time expressions, but both must be of the same type.

The result returned by `TIMEDIFF()` is limited to the range allowed for TIME values. Alternatively, you can use either of the functions `TIMESTAMPDIFF()` and `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()`, both of which return integers.